# AJAX Jquery return message?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this AJAX call

```
$(function() {
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $("form.contact").serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $(".alert-success").toggle();
                    $("#form-content").modal("hide");    
                },
            error: function(){
                $(".alert-error").toggle();
                }
                  });
    });
});
```

The problem is that in process.php i only have

```
echo "OK";
```

In console i see resposne but not on page, what can be problem?

Answer (score 2):

You get `msg` as result of ajax call but you don't use it anywhere. You can use it inside success for example:

```
$(function() {
    $("button#submit").click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $("form.contact").serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                    $(".alert-success").toggle();
                    $("#form-content").modal("hide");
                    //console.log(msg); to get the result in console for example
                },
            error: function(){
                $(".alert-error").toggle();
                }
                  });
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice, how to return from php that msg and use it?

Comment: I showed you in my answer. You can handle the result of your ajax call as you like. Insert in a `div` contaier for example `$("#example").html(msg)` etc..

Comment: Yes, nice. How to back mgs from php ?